# Key range size < 10, each number ∈ [0, 3] of a hash function

Tags: data-structures, hash

I am learning hash table on [Key to Design a Hash Table](https://leetcode.com/explore/learn/card/hash-table/182/practical-applications/1110/)

> #### 1. Hash Function
>
> ---
>
> The hash function is the most important component of a hash table which is used to map the key to a specific bucket. In the example in previous article, we use y = x % 5 as a hash function, where x is the key value and y is the index of the assigned bucket.
>
> The hash function will depend on `the range of key values` and `the number of buckets`.
>
> Here are some examples of hash functions:
>
> [image]
>
> It is an open problem to design a hash function. The idea is to try to assign the key to the bucket as `uniform as you can`. Ideally, a perfect hash function will be a one-one mapping between the key and the bucket. However, in most cases a hash function is not perfect and it is a tradeoff between `the amount of buckets` and `the capacity of a bucket`.

Reference to

```
size < 10, each number ∈ [0, 3]
```

What does `[0,3]` mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means from zero to three inclusive or [0,1,2,3].

Comment: Then how come `4 ** 0 + 4**1 + 4**4?`

Comment: well there are four numbers there if we count them just as there are two numbers in binary if we count [0,1]. the numbers are labels we could label these systems in [apple,banana,cherry,grape] and define a hash function based on those that would be similar.

Comment: why not use `number =2` or `number = 4` straightforwards.

Comment: In one sense I could say well its math notation its something you have to get used to. In another I'd say number of what exactly? we know in this context you mean. If you hand me a blank piece of paper with array of integers  size <10 ```number =4```. What does that mean? Does it mean each number is 4 in the array? Does that mean there are 4 of then and size is their possible values? And if thats the case does size start at zero or 1? You lose more than you gain. At least with notation experienced people know exactly what you are talking about.